# jquery addClass strange problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

my code here http://jsfiddle.net/GKZRU/14/
all js working properly, and add/remove css classes(checking this in chrome js console)
but inactive style doesnt apply, :(
i wanna grey background on radiobutton field that not choosen.

Comment: Please show some of the relevant code here as well to make the question useful for future generations.

Comment: Firebug says: `surpClassAdd is not defined` and `amountClassAdd is not defined`

Comment: An interesting example of how even a really nice tool like jsFiddle can cause weird things to happen if you're not careful :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you've put your code in the "DOM ready" handler via the left-pannel jsFiddle control. The functions are not global.

Try changing the definitions of the functions. Instead of

```
function surpClassAdd() {
```

try

```
window['surpClassAdd'] = function() {
```

Now, obviously in real code you wouldn't need to do that. Another (better) idea would be to quit using "onchange" attributes to bind event handlers, and do things with jQuery (since you're using the library anyway).  Bind the handlers to the elements in your "ready" handler, and the functions need not be global (which is messy and icky anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues.

**1.** Since you've selected `onDomReady` on the sidebar, the functions you defined aren't global. Use `no wrap (head)` instead.

**Note**: you don't need to declare these functions globally if you use jQuery's `.bind()` method (see #5).

**2.** You don't need `<style>` and `</style>` in the CSS pane.

**3.** You're adding the class on the radio button, this has no effect. You should do something like this:

#### HTML

```
<input type='radio' id='foo' name='mybtns' /> <label for='foo'>Label</label>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('label[for=foo]').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
```

Or in this case, do it on the `<td>` elements.

---

**4.** This is just a styling issue, but you should use paragraphs (`<p>text</p>`) instead of simple text nodes (`text`) and line breaks after every line.

**5.** If you don't use inline event handlers and inline styles, instead you write your CSS and JS code in separate files, and reference to them like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/css/default.css' />
<script src='http://mysite.com/js/default.js'></script>
```

Since you're already using jQuery, avoiding inline event handlers is simple: you can use jQuery's `.bind()` function, it will work in all browsers.

```
$('#el').bind('click', function() {
    // your event handler goes here
});
```

Some event handlers (e.g. `click`, `keyup`, `change`) have shorthands:

```
$('#el').click(function() {
    // your event handler goes here
});
```

**6.** [Should I use tables for layout?](http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com) **No.** It's better to use forms in this case.

**7.** Instead of writing `.addClass('active').removeClass('inactive')` in two functions, you can use `.toggleClass('active inactive')` <sup>[*[docs]*](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)</sup> and then you have **one** function instead of two.

Comment: That's all I wanted to say, and written in a really clear way! Mikhail there's some *really good* advice for your code here.

Comment: @Gromix Thanks. I added even more things… and I may add more later.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work in jsFiddle as well, simply bind your functions in javascript instead of in the HTML. Here's a quick example, also cleaned up a bit to remove duplication:
http://jsfiddle.net/GDPvU/1/

A few notes:

- The background color was moved to the parent element (instead of the input)
- You don't need to use `<style>` tags in the jsFiddle CSS panel